# Jquery Button Dialog Box not Closing Immediately when Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button called "Show All", when user click it, it will pop up a window to confirm whether user wants to show all entities. I am using Jquery for this dialog box, I have:

```
function showAll() {
    $("#" + showAllDiv).show();
    $("#" + showAllDiv).dialog( {
         title: XXX,
         height: XXX,
         width: XXX,
         modal : true,
         buttons: {
             "Yes": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  addLoadingFn(); // it will show a "please wait..." dialog
                  heavyDutyWorkFn();  //a function to get all data and show on the pop up HTML window;
                  deleteLoadingFn(); // it will close the "please wait..." dialog
             },
             Cancel: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
    });
    $("#" + showAllDiv).html(You sure to show all?)
 }
```

The problem is, when I click Yes, the dialog does not close immediately. It will still stay for a while until the "heavyDutyWorkFn()" finish its work. In another world, after click "Yes", $(this).dialog("close") will not close, until heavyDutyWorkFn() finish showing all data.

Does anybody know what happened? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `heavyDutyWorkFn()` is a synchronous function, meaning it blocks anything else from happening until it has completed. Perhaps run `heavyDutyWorkFn` on store the result for future use to prevent the delay?

Comment: Thanks! But I am still having some doubts. Why it will block everything else? I am calling "addLoadingFn()" first, should it pop up the window first?

Comment: it blocks everything because thats just how synchronous code works. When you call `heavyDutyWorkFn()` it will execute each line in that function, and only when it reaches the end of the function will `deleteLoadingFn()` then execute. Only after `deleteLoadingFn()` has executed will it register any clicks to 'close' the dialog. So if the `heavyDutyWorkFn` or `deleteLoadingFn()` are slow functions, there's going to be a noticeable delay before closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `heavyDutyWorkFn()` asynchronously with `setTimeout()`, so it doesn't delay the rest of the script.

```
function showAll() {
    $("#" + showAllDiv).dialog( {
         title: XXX,
         height: XXX,
         width: XXX,
         modal : true,
         buttons: {
             "Yes": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  addLoadingFn(); // it will show a "please wait..." dialog
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    heavyDutyWorkFn();  //a function to get all data and show on the pop up HTML window;
                    deleteLoadingFn(); // it will close the "please wait..." dialog
                  }, 1);
             },
             Cancel: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
    }).html("You sure to show all?")
 }
```

BTW, it's not necessary to call `.show()`, since `.dialog()` automatically shows the dialog (unless you use `autoOpen: false`).

Comment: A potential issue with running these functions asynchronously is if they need to modify a piece of the DOM and the dialog has first been closed - thus this piece of DOM could no longer exists - thus raising errors. Just some food for thought.